# Apache делает редирект с добавлением полного пути

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Есть несколько хостов:

- `first.example.com`
- `second.example.com`
- `third.example.com`

У всех одинаковый `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Проблема в том, что когда я обращаюсь к `second.example.com` к какому-нибудь роуту **со слэшем на конце**: например, `second.example.com/hello/world/`; то происходит редирект на `second.example.com/absolute/path/to/webroot/hello/world`.

На `first.example.com` и `third.example.com` всё работает нормально.

Подскажите куда копать?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]`

Comment: @DigitalCore, не помогло; пока выяснил то, что это происходит только по роуту `main/php-info` и только на одном хосте?.. Стоит изменить роут на `main/ph-info` или на `php-inf` — всё работает как полагается ... Может ещё играет роль, что хост называется `info.example.com` ...

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^(data/|js/|styles/|install/|favicon\.ico|crossdomain\.xml|robots\.txt) - [NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]`

Comment: @DigitalCore, тоже не подходит, ума не приложу, почему это происходит ... Именно роут `main/php-info`. Я удалил всё из директории и когда обращаюсь именно к `https:/info.example.com/main/php-info/`, то редиректит на `https:/info.example.com/home/<user>/path/to/webroot/main/php-info`. Стоит убрать любой символ из `main/php-info/` и никакого редиректа нет. Ладно, будет время ещё вернусь к этой проблеме с логами ...

Comment: @DigitalCore, уже ближе: что-то связанное с HTTPS. У меня там Let's Encrypt; когда я отключаю сертификат и работаю по HTTP, то поведение обычное: никакого редиректа.

Comment: @DigitalCore, сегодня включил обратно HTTPS и, о чудо, никаких редиректов ... Может кэш какой где ...